# LDAP server configuration

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am trying to configure a LDAP server for network based system authentication for lab users. I have no domain for my network. But in slapd.conf file for the server configuration the suffix parameters ask for it. what should i provide for that or shall i comment that parameter in slapd.conf file. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The suffix is intended to qualify your entire database so as to make it distinct from all other LDAP databases in the world. The example suffix in slapd.conf should give you a clue as to how to achieve that.